# add_hook seems do not work when I developing the WHMCS

Tags: php, whmcs

I am developing WHMCS, when I read the [Development Document](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/support-tools/#announcementedit), I add a hook of `AnnouncementEdit` in the `xxx/six/includes/hooks/example.php` file:

```
add_hook('AnnouncementEdit', 1, function($vars) {
    // Perform hook code here...

    echo "<script>console.log('announcement_edit');</script>";
    logActivity('Message goes here');
});
```

but when I edit the Announcement, and click the save button, there do not console anything in the browser's console panel. Why? who can tell me where is the issue?

---

**EDIT-01**

Finally, I fond the logActivity in my database, but why the

```
echo "<script>console.log('announcement_edit');</script>";
```

do not execute?
I also tried this code but still not work:

```
echo "{literal}<script>alert('announcement_edit');</script>{/literal}";
```

---

**EDIT-02**

I added a `AnnouncementEdit` hook, and I am sure the hook executed, but the HTML code do not get expect, there is no console nor alert.

```
add_hook("AnnouncementEdit",1,function($vars){
    return <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
    //custom javascript here
    console.log('asdasa');
    alert('announcement_edit');

</script>
HTML;
});
```

---

**EDIT-03**

My Log Errors is ticked.

[image]

Comment: My Assumption here is, because that function does not expect any return or output, it would seem its only expected to be used for things to happen on the backend. With that said multiple things could be causing the issue you are having. Maybe the page is reloading or redirecting before you see the alert, or your output could be causing a php header already sent error that is causing you to not see the alert. Generally if you want to do something with JS on a page in WHMCS I would suggest using the ClientAreaHeadOutput or AdminAreaHeadOutput hooks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
<?php

add_hook('AnnouncementEdit', 1, function($vars) {
    return <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
    //custom javascript here
    console.log('announcement_edit');

</script>
HTML;
});
?>
```

Documentation is available [here](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/output/).

Comment: Where to find the errors log files? where it store in WHMCS?

Comment: See my EDIT-02, bro.

Comment: for log errors: in WHMCS Navigate to Setup > General Settings > Other
Tick the Display Errors checkbox located towards the bottom of the page
Click Save Changes